# how to web scrape website which requires active directory(GNS login credentials) password using python

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, active-directory

I am new in web scraping, I am working on web scraping internal website, If I try to access it using chrome /IE it get auto login (I didn't find any login page for the same).I tried to reach to that website address using beautiful soup,but it showed authentication failed .After research , I come to know that it may be because of active directory. Could you please help me in this.

[Error-401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFU52.png)

Comment: You should add stack trace here itself for us to see.

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import  urlopen

myUrl='http://netbuild/Pages/OrderSearch.aspx'
uClient=urlopen(myUrl)
pageHtml=uClient.read()
uClient.close()

OutPut:-

 File "P:\Users\mungilwar.shubham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "P:\Users\mungilwar.shubham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized